# Fail when joining 2 jsons data sets in BQ

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I want to join two tables for JSON sources

Table 1 has 2 strings `columns (id(string), ....)`
Table 2 has 2 strings `columns` and 3 repeated `(id(string), categories(repeated), ...`

inside the repeated, there is only one layer down.

when I am trying to join between 2 tables it keeps failing:

```
select * FROM source.tableA a
inner join  source.tableB b
on (a.id = b.id)

limit 5
```

**Error:**
Error while reading table: source.tableB, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up.

> Rows: 1396313; errors: 1.

Please look into the error stream for more details.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: it looks like you have federated table (table that references an external data source) on top of file in Cloud Storage. Please confirm/clarify

Answer (score 0):

The following command should work.

select * from source.tableA inner join source.tableB on (source.tableA.id = source.tableB.id);

Comment: If not, can you please provide more details about the Data Schema? What do you mean by "inside the repeated, there is only one layer down."